# osgeo/ogr function that smooths geometry/vertex like qgis/processing toolbox/smooth

Tags: gdal, ogr, osgeo

In QGIS, I want smooth a shapefile/vector's vertices.

I can use QGIS/processing_toolbox/smooth.

If I want to programmingly achieve this using osgeo/ogr/gdal, which function should I use?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is absolutely possible using `GDAL/OGR` through `ogr2ogr` by using `-simplify` option. You should pass a `<tolerance>` value as it is described [on their website.](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html#cmdoption-ogr2ogr-simplify)

Another way is to use `osgeo.ogr.Geometry.Buffer(self, *args, **kwargs)` on which supports arguments to control distance and number of segments.

If your shapes are polylines you can use `shapely->parallel_offset` as well. which has a `round` option.
Good Luck.

Comment: Smoothing is not the same as simplify. The tool description begins "Smooth
This algorithm smooths the geometries in a line or polygon layer. It creates a new layer with the same features as the ones in the input layer, but with geometries containing a higher number of vertices and corners in the geometries smoothed out."

Answer (score 0):

You could use GRASS GIS:

Create `grass_batch_job.sh` file for GRASS GIS:

```
v.in.ogr min_area=0.0001 snap=-1.0 input="input_file.shp" output="my_vector" --overwrite -o
v.generalize input=my_vector type="line,boundary,area" method="chaiken" threshold=1 look_ahead=7 reduction=50 slide=0.5 angle_thresh=3 degree_thresh=0 closeness_thresh=0 betweeness_thresh=0 alpha=1 beta=1 iterations=1 -l output=my_output --overwrite
v.out.ogr type="auto" input="my_output" output="smooth.gpkg" format="GPKG" --overwrite
```

now run it with `grass --tmp-location EPSG:8353 --exec sh grass_batch_job.sh`

(modify EPSG and `input_file.shp` according to your needs)